# sql: подсчет строк с определенным шагом для интервалов

Tags: sql, postgresql

Такой вопрос:

Есть таблица условно сотрудников (имя, зарплата). Нужно за один запрос посчитать кол-во сотрудников с зарплатой в интервалах от 0 до 10000, 100000 до 20000 и так далее.
Через case when нельзя, так как придется писать интервалы вручную, их может быть бесконечно много.

Как написать запрос в sql, чтобы поставить нужный мне шаг интервала и посчитать кол-во записей в каждом из них?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Вы можете вычислить Округлить_вверх(зарплата / 10000) и группировать по нему. Значение 1 соответствует первому интервалу, 2 второму и так далее.